# Which is correct sentence? Use of verb with would

Tags: verbs, sentence

I am having little difficulty with the use of would.
Here are two examples that are making me confused about use of verb with **would**.

- What would happen if he loses the match?
- What would happen if he lost the match?

Which one of these two is correct?

Comment: This would probably be more appropriate on English Language Learners, but only after you did some research.  Start with looking up the definition of the word would, and then look at the difference between lost and loses.  If  you are still confused, post it there instead.

Comment: Yeah! I searched and kept on reading for almost 2 and half hours, but this was confusing me. @user2310967less answered what I was expecting. Waiting for more awesome answers, if there is any more explanation.

Comment: This link question got answer which suggests both can be used.

Comment: I agree with @phenry that you will find some useful information in the marked duplicate. I think John Lawler's comment there is particularly interesting.

Answer (score 1):

"What would happen if he lost the match?" is the correct construction - use of the subjunctive 'would' in the consequent implies past or past perfect in the condition. It's known as a "contrary to fact" condition because it's meant to describe situations that are not (presently) the case. You could just as correctly say "What happens if he loses?", both verbs in the present tense, with only a slight difference in connotation.

Comment: But you could also say 'What would happen should he lose the match?', or 'What would happen were he to lose the match?'. I am afraid that I am not grammarist enough to explain the varieties of the subjunctive employed here. I would be interested were anyone to oblige.

Comment: You could say, of "What would happen, were he to lose the match" (a form of the contrary-to-fact condition: note the past subjunctive _were_ for what is other was indicative _was_) or "What _will_ happen, should he lose the match?" That is, you inquire about future consequences but express uncertainty that the condition (he loses) will be met. However, in modern English it's not a very common construction and sounds a little old-fashioned.

Comment: How would you therefore express 'What would happen in Brazil this June, should England win the World Cup?' (an unlikely proposition).

Comment: As: "What would happen in Brazil this June, if England were to win the World Cup?" or "What will happen in Brazil this June, if England wins the World Cup?"

"What will happen in Brazil this June, if England should win the World Cup?" is grammatically correct, but sounds almost deliberately archaic.

Comment: @ Doesn't to my ear! Though I have no objection to the alternatives you propose.